# Passing key as a <li> prop in react

Tags: reactjs

In my react application, I created a component for

. It is as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ListItem = props => {
   const { className, key, children } = props; 

   return (
      <li key={key} className={className}>
         {children}
      </li>
   );
}

ListItem.propTypes = { 
   className: PropTypes.string,
   key: PropTypes.string
}

export default ListItem;
```

When I try to use it as this,

```
<ListItem key={index} className="list-group-item">{skill}</ListItem>
```

It gives the following error.
*ListItem: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned.*

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `key` is a private keyword that cannot be used in props. `key` value should be unique inside a "list of items" to improve the reconciliation of React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key has a special meaning in React, and is not normally available via the `this.props`. see the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#dynamic-children) as well

Key is only necessary with dynamic children, where you can do something like this:

```js
const listItems = list ? (
  list.map((item, i) => (
    <li key={i} className="b-list__item">
      {item.keyword}
    </li>
  ))
) : null;
```